# How to make the dropdown option of a select box

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, for-loop, foreach

I'm building a train web booking project. Now I need to build a selectbox and the option value is varied based on the booking form.

```
//select-box
<custom-select-box
    label="Travel"
    v-model="form.InfantWithAdult"
    :items="travel"
></custom-select-box>
```